# calling serverside method from javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, pagemethods

I want to call server side C# function from javascript.

I used the way given in [this article](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/).

This works fine when I did the same steps in a new ASP.NET application.
But when I repeat the same steps in the application on which i am working it give the error:

> "PageMethods is Undefined".

I am working on .Net 4.0.

Comment: You must have at least one page method in the page class in code behind. Having it in control won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled page methods on your scriptmanager?

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
    EnablePageMethods="true" 
    runat="server" />`

Comment: I did all the things that are given in the article, and its working in  a new application. When i do that same in my old website, it doesn't work. I tried it in ascx and aspx both control and page.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a ScriptManager control?

As an alternative to trying to get the PageMethods approach to work, I would recommend switching to the more up to date WCF Script Services:

- [Exposing WCF Services to Client
  Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514961%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Forget Page Methods move
  on to Script Services](http://markkemper1.blogspot.com/2007/11/forget-page-methods-move-on-to-script.html)